# Text to this song by Mühlenhof Musikanten?

Tags: music

This is one of my favorite German songs but there is no song text for it anywhere.

„Zogen einst viel schöne Weisen“
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPsW6q1C4JA

If anyone can get the text I appreciate it!

Comment: not an answer but related to your question: it might be interesting for you that the version above uses the melody and some text-references of "Zogen einst 5 wilde Schwäne", an old anti-war song.  https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zogen_einst_f%C3%BCnf_wilde_Schw%C3%A4ne

Comment: I find a lot of song lyrics at lyricstranslate.com. It might be easier to find a song there and look for it on YouTube rather than starting on YouTube and trying to find the lyrics.

Answer (score 3):

Zogen einst viel schöne Weisen,
<s>gingen</s> singend durch das deutsche Land,
auf den wundersamen Reisen,
jede ein Zuhause fand.

Ost, West, Nord und Süd,
jeder hat sein eigenes schönes Lied,
doch was wird geschehen,
wenn sie wieder auf die Reise gehen.

Die Lieder, sie wandern,
denn von einem Ort zum anderen,
und wie sie da klingen,
ja da singen wir heut von.

Comment: @Hansel It is the full song sung in the video.

Comment: Hey what's up. If it is not too much to ask then I was wondering if you could do the rest of the songs? Best wishes and appreciate your help.

Comment: "Ja, das singen wir euch heut."