# Can someone help me translate this collection of songs by Mühlenhof Musikanten?

Tags: music

I was wondering if anyone can help me with the lyrics to this collection of songs in the video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPsW6q1C4JA

I would appreciate very much if someone can get the full text to each song.

Comment: This is the first song. Credit to Oran Matheus.

Zogen einst viel schöne Weisen,
gingen durch das deutsche Land,
auf den wundersamen Reisen,
jede ein Zuhause fand

Ost, West, Nord und Süd,
jeder hat sein eigenes schönes Lied,
doch was wird geschehen,
wenn sie wieder auf die Reise gehen

Die Lieder, sie wandern,
denn von einem Ort zum anderen,
und wie sie da klingen,
ja da singen wir heut von

Comment: Do you mean translate or transcribe?

Comment: Are you going to ask the same question a few more times? [Can anyone help me with the text to this song by Mühlenhof Musikanten?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/74846/can-anyone-help-me-with-the-text-to-this-song-by-m%c3%bchlenhof-musikanten)

Comment: @OranMatheus I mean transcribe since I can then translate using an online one to learn the German vocabulary.